# right parenthesis error ORA-00907 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created these 2 tables. They are part of a superType of staff. When trying to create these tables in oracle I am getting the error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. can anyone point out my mistake?

Firstaiders Table

```
DROP TABLE Firstaiders;
CREATE TABLE Firstaiders(
Staff_ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT  pk_Firstaiders PRIMARY KEY (Staff_ID),

FOREIGN KEY(Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON   UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Security Table

```
 DROP TABLE Security;
CREATE TABLE Security(
Staff_ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,
Security_ID NUMBER,
CRB_CHECK   VARCHAR2(8),
fk1_Stage_ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT  pk_Security PRIMARY KEY (Staff_ID),

FOREIGN KEY(Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ON UPDATE CASCADE` which is not supported directly in Oracle.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Firstaiders(
Staff_ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  pk_Firstaiders PRIMARY KEY (Staff_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Oracle expects a right parenthesis after `ON DELETE CASCADE` but it found `ON UPDATE CASCADE` that's causing the `ORA-00907`