# ORA-00905: missing keyword ora

Tags: oracle

> ALTER TABLE BAND ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_BAND_to_VENUE FOREIGN KE
>   ORA-00905: missing keyword

how do i solve this problem, this sql was created with QSEE application from the EDR diagram. i dont think the SQL sntax is wrong.

-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "BAND_FESTIVAL" relationship

-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "BAND"
-- correctly references the primary key of table "FESTIVAL"

```
ALTER TABLE BAND 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk2_BAND_to_FESTIVAL 
FOREIGN KEY(fk2_Festival_ID) REFERENCES FESTIVAL(Festival_ID) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

-- Alter table to add new constraints required to implement the "work" relationship

-- This constraint ensures that the foreign key of table "STAFF"
-- correctly references the primary key of table "FESTIVAL"

Comment: Which database are you actually using?

Comment: If this is Oracle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790751/right-paranthesis-error/47790998#47790998

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, and I would have expected it to work.  Can you post a minimal sample of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-00905 suggests that this *is* Oracle. [12c constraint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) says that the only valid options for **ON DELETE** are

- CASCADE
- SET NULL

There's no ON UPDATE at all (so - no options for it either).

Those options are, though, valid for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Therefore, @sarthak sthapit, make up your mind - if you're on Oracle, use its syntax; if you're on MySQL, use its syntax. They are partially compatible, but not always (as you can see).